# How can we set dropdown value selected in update page , and the selected value must be the actual value of that item in database?

Tags: php, node.js

In any programming language and database system. This is particularly for the update page where old values are to be shown on the page. If we don't want to change the value of that dropdown option, but still we have to change it to the original value. That's the main problem.

here are the example :[first: list of products with its category name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oedS.png)

[particular product detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtlrF.png)

here in the second image I just want to change the price but I also have to change its category due to the problem

Comment: mysql and mongodb are two different database products, therefore I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use. For mysql-php combo this question has already been asked and answered here on SO.

Comment: What is the dropdown list of that you want to display?

Comment: The category of a product. Have fixed with the solution provided by you @Tushar. Sorry I am too late to reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to loop over your collection of items and perform a check that if the update page's item's property (let's assume id) matches the one you are iterating over, if yes then you want to set values to display otherwise skip.